# connecting api with real device flutter

Tags: laravel, api, flutter, flutter-web, laravel-api

I'm facing a problem when I run my flutter project in a real device, the API and the app works perfectly in an emulator, but when I change the URL using this one (I'm using laravel to write my API and it works in the postman):

[image]

I got an error in the `response.body` but the `response.statusCod`e is good

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your real device is not in the same network as your PC.
Connect to your wifi and try again

Comment: it is in the same wifi i checked

Comment: Then you have to check if your server is available from the phone itself via browser lets say. Maybe the problem is with your network

Comment: yes it's available i can access to my project file via my phone by using the same adress

Comment: Ok, I didn't mentioned that your statusCode is Ok. 
What library do you use for HTTP request then?

Comment: i'm using this one http: ^0.12.0+2

Comment: check internet permission

Comment: I checked internet permission an all is good in my main\manifest and debug\manifest and profile\manifest , Unfortunately the same problem with the same error

Answer (score 2):

open vscode and in terminal : php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.100
don't clos vscode (terminal)
open android studio run in real device via usb,in my case it works,

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.100 use this ip address!
in your code ip address wrong,
change 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.100